# Setting HttpCookie as HttpOnly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token

I'm setting a cookie specifically using the following code:

```
System.Web.HttpCookie cookie = new System.Web.HttpCookie("MyCookie", accessToken)
{
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30),
    HttpOnly = false,
    Domain = ".mywebsite.com",
    Path = "/"
};
```

I also have the below entry on my web.config:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" lockItem="true"/>
```

What happened until today was that all cookies were set as `HttpOnly` except `MyCookie` which is what I want.

But something strange happened today. I deployed my web application with the same code and the `MyCookie` is being set as `HttpOnly`.

So I have two different installations with different behaviors right now.

So my question is : Is there any other configuration or OS / IIS version that overrides the cookie creation method settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

HttpOnly is browser-dependant but is available to most common browsers.  For the .NET world, this can be set as you have above against a cookie.  However, if you are using [.NET Core](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/15/httponly-cookies-asp-net-core/), there is no longer the default mentioned below in the web.config unless you are using IIS, so you must set it on every cookie.

Considering what is below agrees with what you have in your code, I would double check that nothing else is modifying your cookies after you have set them.  Have you checked by adding debug code after that cookie definition above that the value of HttpOnly is true? I would also try to retrieve the cookie in a new variable to make sure that it is the same as well.

#### Taken from the [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#Using_.NET_to_Set_HttpOnly) website:

By default, .NET 2.0 sets the HttpOnly attribute for
 - Session ID
 - Forms Authentication cookie

In .NET 2.0, HttpOnly can also be set via the HttpCookie object for all custom application cookies

Via web.config in the system.web/httpCookies element

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" …>
```

Or programmatically

**C# Code:**

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie");
myCookie.HttpOnly = true;
Response.AppendCookie(myCookie);
```

**VB.NET Code:**

```
Dim myCookie As HttpCookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie")
myCookie.HttpOnly = True
Response.AppendCookie(myCookie)
```

However, in .NET 1.1, you would have to do this manually, e.g.,

```
Response.Cookies[cookie].Path += ";HttpOnly";
```